# Internet Explorer doesn't make file download, only characters appear

Tags: java, internet-explorer, facescontext

Internet Explorer doesn't make file download, only characters appear.

Just Microsoft Office files for example (.doc,.xls,.docx)

This is my code:

*.jspx :

```
      <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{LicitacaoControl.download}" icon="ui-icon-circle-zoomin" title="Visualizar Arquivo" ajax="false">
           <f:param id="visualizar" name="visualizar" value="#{arquivo}" />
      </p:commandButton>
```

Controller.java

```
public void download(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        Arquivo arquivo = (Arquivo) UtilFaces.getValorParametro(evt, "visualizar");
        HttpServletResponse resp = UtilFaces.getResponse();
        resp.addHeader("Content-disposition", String.format("inline; filename=\"%s.%s\"", arquivo.getDescricao(), arquivo.getExtensao()));
        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        out.write(arquivo.getDados());
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        out.close();
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        UtilFaces.addMensagemFaces(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a download you should be using `Content-Disposition: attachment` rather than `Content-Disposition: inline`. Displaying a file inline is the opposite of downloading it.

Comment: right .. Thank you, but I would like to show a file instead of downloading. how to do this?